# Как добавить полифилл?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, кроссбраузерность

Имеется следующий код

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.minus').click(function() {
       this.nextElementSibling.stepDown()
    });
    $('.plus').click(function() {
       this.previousElementSibling.stepUp();
    });
});
```

Необходимо добавить полифиллы для поддержки previousElementSibling и nextElementSibling в IE:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling

Как правильно добавить указанные полифиллы?

Comment: для какого браузера?

Comment: Для IE 10 и далее

Comment: @AlexandrJärvi, ну-ну... IE9+ уже сам умеет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, верно)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то надо просто код нормально написать:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.minus').click(function() {
     $(this).next().val(function (i, x) { return +x - 1 });
  });
  $('.plus').click(function() {
     $(this).prev().val(function (i, x) { return +x + 1 });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product_amount">
  <button class="minus" type="button">-</button>
  <input class="change_amount" type="text" min="1" max="100" value="1" disabled>
  <button class="plus" type="button">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: В таком случае кнопки перестают работать, тогда как с js, указанным в тексте вопроса, они работают (но не работают в IE)
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGmJPj

Comment: @AlexandrJärvi, а по-твоему `<input type="number">` там вообще поддерживается?

Comment: @AlexandrJärvi, обновил ответ

Comment: ок, заработало, благодарю

Answer (score 0):

nextElementSibling:

```
if (document.documentElement.nextElementSibling === undefined) {    
    Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "nextElementSibling", {
          get: function(){
            var el = this.nextSibling;
            while (el && el.nodeType !== 1) { el = el.nextSibling; }
            return (el.nodeType === 1) ? el : null;
          }
        });
}
```

previousElementSibling:

```
if (document.documentElement.previousElementSibling === undefined) {    
    Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "previousElementSibling", {
          get: function(){
            var el = this.previousSibling;
            while (el && el.nodeType !== 1) { el = el.previousSibling; }
            return (el.nodeType === 1) ? el : null;
          }
        });
}
```

Comment: Вот прям ржу.. Ты под какой браузер это написал?

Comment: @Qwertiy, IE8, проверяй ;)

Comment: Хм.. А он разве умеет `Object.defineProperty`? Хотя, MDN говорит, что на dom-элементах - да... И почему проверка в if такая странная?